# How to use amazon api gateway for existing api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, loopbackjs, strongloop, aws-api-gateway

I have an API and I am trying to make it secure by using amazon api gateway but I get error as

```
{
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

`[I have loopback API (strongloop) API running][1]`

So at first I created resource `memberdetails` and then method `getMembers` and specified `Query Strings` however when I try test it, it gives me

> 500 error code.

I have tried the same endpoint in postman and I get the response with valid data as `JSON.`

I think I have got it all wrong.**Need some assistance on this.**

Thanks

Comment: Okay, so what does *your API server* show, in its logs, related to this request?  Does it seem like it's even receiving the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 Internal Server Error could happen due to various root causes including API configuration issues. You can use the TestInvoke feature in the API Gateway console to test your API before deploying. The Test Invoke feature would display detailed response and the logs. That should give a better insight about your issue.

If that doesn't help and if you have configured your API as per [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/create-api-resources-methods.html), please reach out to us using AWS Forums or create a support case where we can get more details from you about your rest API.

Comment: I have deployed API and also have the api key with which I am able to make the requests however I also want to implement security for the api deployed. But I want to also implement security for my api thats where I am stuck.

Comment: Also to mention that the api is deployed with HTTP Proxy as integration.